# TFS 2013 won't build a .NET Framework 4.6 project

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, .net-4.6

I am trying to get TFS2013 to build a .NET Framework 4.6 C# project on our build servers. I have installed the build tools and the 4.6 .NET Framework out on the build machine. I can see from the build log that the build server is actually targeting the 4.6 .NET Framework.

Earlier I had issues getting the dll references but those were cleaned up by me installing the 4.6 framework. I even tried installing Visual Studio 2015 on the build server and still it won't build.

I have also tried passing the /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 parameter. I am kind of running out of ideas or things to try to get this build working.

Comment: Are there any specific error messages?

Comment: @mikez just compiler errors that are new syntax for 4.6 something like  `public bool readOnlyProp => ( a >= b);`

Comment: Not that there is a difference between the new framework (4.6) and the new C# version (6.0). A newer framework does not neccesarily need a new compiler. What you acutally want, is to plugin the new  C# 6-compiler (fka 'Roslyn') into tfs 2013. I'd like that too, so +1 for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what i needed to do.

To let TFS2013 run builds for 4.6 you need to do the following:
Install the 4.6 framework and the Build Tools for 2015.

OR

Install Visual Studio 2015 (which installs the framework and build tools).

Then you can either modify your build template and hard code the build tools for a template. Or the path I choose that was use the argument:  /tv:14.0

Comment: Thank you, where did you put the /tv arg?

Comment: @AdamPlocher On my build definition, Go to the Process Tab where you choose your template. Under the 2.Build section there should be an arrow you can expand called "Advanced". In the MS Build arguments you can use /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 or /tv:14.0    one is the property for the version one is the short hand toolversion They should be the same setting though.